# Bound for Gaussian convolution roots

Tags: real-analysis, roots, convolution, heat-equation

I am struggling on the following problem.

#### The problem

Let $f$ be a real function, smooth, Lipschitz continuous and bounded. Let assume that $f$ is negative before 0 and positive after. For $\sigma>0$, we define the gaussian convolution $E$ by :

$$E(x,\sigma)\triangleq \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}f(s)e^{-\frac{(s-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}}ds.$$

We know that under these conditions, the function $E(\cdot,\sigma)$ has only one zero-crossing denoted $x_\sigma$.

The problem is: Can we found a constant $K$ such that $|x_\sigma|\leq K\sigma^2$ ?

#### What we know

- In [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452276/distance-between-root-of-f-and-its-gaussian-convolution), it is shown that this approximation exists for $\sigma$ tending to zero.
- It is perhaps useful to note that $E$ is the solution of the heat equation problem $\mathcal{P}$:

$$\mathcal{P} : \begin{cases}\partial_\sigma E(x,\sigma) = \sigma\partial_{xx}E(x,\sigma) \\ E(x,0) = f(x)\end{cases}.$$

- One can notice that the function is equal to:
  $$E(x,\sigma) = \mathbb{E}(f(x+\sigma Z)), ~Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1).$$

Thank you very much!

Comment: "$f$ is negative before $0$ and negative after" -- so $f$ is negative almost everywhere, so $E(x,\sigma)<0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thank you @user10354138 for noticing the error, I have edited the post. $f$ is negative before 0 and positive after.

Comment: Is the constant $K$ allowed to depend on $f$?

Comment: Yes Adam it can.